# Ipad Air iOS 8.4 Restrictions passcode forgotten

Tags: password, ios, restore, ipad

How do i recover/reset/remove restictions passcode on iOS 8.4 ?
I have already tried :
SBParentalControlsFailedAttempts
X
SBParentalControlsPIN
1234.

No result obtained .
Please advise.
Thanks in advance.